# How to remove menu with easymenu?

Tags: menus, easy-menu

Easymenu is great for creating menus, but how can you remove a top-level menu that was created with it?

Here's an example.  A minor mode might create the following menu:

```
  (easy-menu-define some-minor-mode-menu some-minor-mode-map
    "Menu keymap for some minor mode."
    '("Menu"
      ["Item" command t]
      ...))
```

How would you remove this menu from the menubar using easymenu's own commands?  Unfortunately, easymenu is poorly documented and all the available documentation is about how to *add* menus and submenus.

(I have been able to remove this sort of menu by adding `(define-key some-minor-mode-map [menu-bar Menu] nil)` to the major mode's hook, but is that the only way to do it?  Does easymenu provide no facilities for this?)

Comment: Do the last two messages in [this conversation](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/How-to-delete-item-from-menu-bar-td59803.html) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  The penultimate message there is the same as the solution I came up with.  The solution with easy-menu-remove in the last message does not work for me -- it does remove the menu in question, but also several others and some other customizations don't load any more.  Perhaps it has to be put into a hook. I'll investigate further.  This might be trivial if easymenu were properly documented.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution: use the `:visible` or `:active` properties of the fourth parameter of `easy-menu-define`.

Say you have defined a menu like this:

```lisp
(easy-menu-define org-glaux-menu global-map "Org-glaux"
  (list "Org-glaux"
        ...
  ))
```

You can disable it with:

```lisp
(easy-menu-define nil global-map nil 
  (list "Org-glaux" :visible nil))
```

Replacing `:visible` to `:active` also works. It would not be too hard to
warp it into a function:

```lisp
(defun my/easy-menu-remove (maps menu-name)
  "Remove MENU-NAME from the current menu bar."
  (easy-menu-define nil maps nil 
            (list menu-name :visible nil)))
```

See the documentation of `easy-menu-define`:

> The first element of MENU must be a string.  It is the menu bar
> item name.  It may be followed by the following keyword argument
> pairs:
>
> ...
>
> :visible INCLUDE
>
> ```
> INCLUDE is an expression.  The menu is visible if the
> expression evaluates to a non-nil value.  ‘:included’ is an
> alias for ‘:visible’.
> ```
>
> :active ENABLE
>
> ```
> ENABLE is an expression.  The menu is enabled for selection
> if the expression evaluates to a non-nil value.  ‘:enable’ is
> an alias for ‘:active’.
> ```

A relevant comment from the documentation of `easy-menu-remove`:

> (easy-menu-remove MENU)
>
> This function is obsolete since 28.1;
> use ‘ignore’ instead.
> This function does not change global state, including the match data.
>
> Remove MENU from the current menu bar.
> Contrary to XEmacs, this is a nop on Emacs since **menus are automatically
> (de)activated when the corresponding keymap is (de)activated**.